no refresca el javascript en navegadores moviles
no se actualizan archivos javascript en el navegador
el proyecto que estoy modificando esta en este tipo de servidor portable ver imagen adjunta
al momento que hago cambios en los archivos js y lanzo el servidor en el ambiente de producción no se reflejan los cambios realizados es decir los navegadores no toman esos cambios realizados si no unos dias despues
no se si me podrian colaborar con algun tipo de etiqueta meta que solicite que se refresquen los archivos js


No se entiende cual es el error ni cual el resultado esperado, deberías añadir algo más a la respuesta. Ese pantallazo que vemos ¿qué es? una aplicación que estás desarrollando?

Hola Alonso, te sugiero que cambies el título, a algo como, como hacer para que el servidor refleje los cambios en el archivo .js de inmediato?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
